# How can I get cumsum of datetime with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get `cumsum` over a column using datetime index every 24 hours? I tried the following code that gives me cumsum incrementally. But I want cusum to restart at every 24 hours.

input

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '2020-01-01 06:00:00', 
                    1: '2020-01-01 18:00:00', 
                    2: '2020-01-02 06:00:00',
                    3: '2020-01-02 18:00:00',
                    4: '2020-01-03 06:00:00',
                    5: '2020-01-03 18:00:00',
                    6: '2020-01-04 06:00:00',
                    7: '2020-01-04 18:00:00'},
              'B': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3:6, 4:7, 5:7, 6:1, 7:1}})
```

code

```
input2= df.set_index('A')
input2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = '24H', base=6)).cumsum()
```

desired output

```
A   B
2020-01-01 06:00:00 5
2020-01-01 18:00:00 10
2020-01-02 06:00:00 6
2020-01-02 18:00:00 12
2020-01-03 06:00:00 7
2020-01-03 18:00:00 14
2020-01-04 06:00:00 1
2020-01-04 18:00:00 2
```

Comment: the expected output looks like more to be grouper per 24h, so try `input2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = '24H', base=6)).cumsum()` maybe add more rows with different hours to actually see what you mean by the 12h cumsum

Comment: The index was causing the problem. This worked for me. `df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])` Thanks anyways.